# Are there monochrome camera sensors with more than 16 bit depth per pixel?

Tags: sensor, camera, resolution

Some camera use cases (like [exoplanet transit photometry](https://www.planetary.org/articles/down-in-front-the-transit-photometry-method)) require measuring smaller variations in brightness across an image and over time than the bit depth resolution in 16 bit monochrome cameras can afford (2^16=65536 counts, where the detected variation is just a tiny fraction of that.)

Do (monochrome) camera sensors beyond 16 bits per pixel exist?

Comment: hm stupid question, since I'm not familiar with the sensors for such use cases, but aren't they photon counters, essentially? meaning that more bits doesn't improve the lower end of measurement, just the maximum count per cell?

Comment: If a photomultiplier tube can count single photons, quantifying brightness takes on a different perspective.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes they are essentially counting photons and some noise, so more bits means more dynamic range on the high end. High bit cameras are frequently used to measure small signals on top of large offsets (variations in brightness). They are useless (or at least no better) for dim signals that would fit into fewer bits.

Comment: I am not an astronomer but if I wanted to track the brightness of a star over time I would record many sequential frames and then filter the output to generate a plot of photons per second over the interval. In this scheme the (per frame) dynamic range of the ADC would not be a limiting factor. This would have other advantages, including the ability to track the star as the Earth moves and the ability to look at variations at different time scales.

Comment: Astrophotography at that level involves large amounts of post-processing of the data, including sometimes "stacking" dozens or even hundreds of individual exposures in order to increase the overall dynamic range.

Comment: Detecting planets via transit of their star should be possible with 16 bit sensors.  Take the earth and the sun.  If the earth transits the sun, it changes the apparent brightness of the sun by .01%, or 1 part in 10,000.  So a 16-bit sensor should be able to detect that change.  Throw in a large number of samples over time and some signal processing improves things even more.

Comment: @SteveSh For ground based telescopes, the noise/errors during the acquisition process will probably overwhelm the ~6 count difference out of 65536 that will be detected. But as you say, with a large number of samples it may be possible to statistically detect it.

Comment: @2080 - Agree.  My example was for an earth size planet.  For a planet the size of Jupiter, the brightness change is a much larger 1% - 1 part in 100.

Answer (score 2):

I looked up the sensors for the PLAnetary Transits and Oscillations of stars (PLATO) space telescope:

https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/10564/1056405/The-PLATO-camera/10.1117/12.2309075.full?SSO=1

It uses 32 81x81mm CCD (not CMOS) sensors, each with 4510x4510 18 micron wide pixels. Due to the enormous pixels, the saturation power is nearly 1 million photons, far more than could be counted with a 16 bit sensor.

They split the array up into fast (2.5s) and slow (tens of seconds) exposure sensors, with the former being used for orientation and angular control of the space craft. The latter do long exposure to monitor the brightness of stars.

Interestingly they use 14 bit ADCs for the fast sensors and 16 bit for the long integration time slow sensors. No explanation is given, but presumably they do not require more than 16 bits dynamic range (although they could have chosen more).

Stopping at 16 bit probably makes sense. 96 dB dynamic range is very high for an optical signal given shot noise statistics. Considering shot noise, at saturation the sensor would have a shot noise standard deviation of nearly 1000 photons (sqrt(N)). If the gain of the ADCs was set to 10 photons per DN for an experiment, they could record up to 655350 photons per pixel and still have a quantization step size 100-fold smaller than the shot noise. At the same time, the sensor read noise is more than 20 photons, so their quantization size would also be less than half the minimum sensitivity, so they aren't losing anything at the low end either.

I'm not sure if anyone has ever made a sensor with >16 bits. Probably someone somewhere has, but as you can see it requires truly extreme conditions to make much difference. Often I suspect 16 bit is used because relatively cost effective, not because it will have a significant effect on real images.